# Cannot access state inside callback

Tags: reactjs

I've foreach function where I'm iterating the markers and calling getDetails function. At the end of getDetails, I'm calling callback function when all elements are processed. Inside callback I'm trying to access state property but I'm unable to access it. I've tried using bind method however error I'm getting is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of null.

```
export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    markers: []
    value: ''
  }

 handleChange(event) {
   callback = () => {
     console.log(this.state.markers);
   }
   markers.forEach((place,index) => {
     .....
     services.getDetails(request, (place, status) =>  {
        if(place != null){
            .....
        }else{

        }

        itemsProcessed++;
        if(itemsProcessed === markers.length) {
            this.callback();
        }
    });
   });
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare callback function with arrow function like this

```
callback = () => {
    console.log(this.state.markers);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
if(itemsProcessed === markers.length) {
   this.callback();
}
```

**Update::**
You are not binding your handlechange function with class. So first you need to bind your handlechange function. A better way to do this is to use arrow function like this::

```
handleChange = (event) => {
```

Now if you want to keep your callback function out of handlechange function then you can do like this ([Link of working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5yqYwyP3q))::

```
callback = () => {
     console.log(this.state.markers);
   }

  handleChange = (event) => {
   ...
   markers.forEach((place,index) => {
     services.getDetails(place, (place, status) =>  {
        itemsProcessed++;
        if(itemsProcessed === markers.length) {
            this.callback();
        }
    });
   });
 }
```

Or if you want to keep your callback function inside handlechang function then you can do it like this([Link of working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/VJkDDZ89))::

```
handleChange = (event) => {
   let callback = () => {
     console.log(this.state.markers);
   }
   ...
   markers.forEach((place,index) => {
     services.getDetails(place, (place, status) =>  {
        itemsProcessed++;
        if(itemsProcessed === markers.length) {
            callback();
        }
    });
   });
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Prakash I've tried your sol. but I'm getting this error -> Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (88:17) at callback => () {

Comment: Now I'm getting  ReferenceError: callback is not defined and also, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'callback' of null

Comment: Yes it's inside my class ...export default class extends Component {

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151804/discussion-between-shanky-and-prakash-sharma).

Comment: Thanks it worked. I wasn't calling my handleChange with arrow function.